# Are there Chainlink Contacts / Nodes for Ropsten?

Tags: chainlink

I noticed on the [official docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses#rinkeby) the networks are

Mainnet
Kovan
Rinkeby

Are there Chainlink Contacts / Nodes for Ropsten?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but a lot of node operators got off ropsten when ropsten had its reorganization. So it's not as supported as rinkeby or kovan.